# Autohotkey, Step by Step Execution

Tags: macros, autohotkey

This may be a very simple code but I am not able to find how to do it.

I have this 
Send, Hi
Send, How Are you
Send, I am Fine

I want to do it like this
Hi How Are you 
....

Right now with the below code

KeyWait, Capslock
Send, Hi
KeyWait, Capslock
Send, How Are you
KeyWait, Capslock
Send, I am Fine

I get
HiHow Are YOuI Am Fine as soon as I press Capslock.

I want it to wait to execute the next command. THanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```php
KeyWait, Capslock
Send {Capslock} ; Tap it again to reset it and force it to be released
; or Send {Capslock Up} to force it to be released
; or SetCapslockState Off to disable it completley
Send, Hi KeyWait, Capslock{Enter}
Send, How Are you KeyWait, Capslock{Enter}
Send, I am Fine{Enter}
```

If you want it in a hotkey, you could do something like this.

```php
~$CapsLock::
Send {CapsLock Up}
Send, Hi {Enter}
KeyWait, Capslock, D
Send {CapsLock Up}
Send, How Are you{Enter} 
KeyWait, Capslock
Send {CapsLock Up}
Send, I am Fine{Enter}
return
```

(It's glitching on my computer, but it may be because I'm on a virtual machine.)

[SetCapslockState](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm)

Comment: For some reason your superior solution does NOT work at all. Any idea why?

Comment: I didn't mean to anger you; sorry.  Does the second work for you?

Comment: It might be that I use AHK_L, but your solution still doesn't work. It now prints everything at once including the text Capslock. Sorry, it annoys me when someone votes a (working) suggestion down only to come up with a technically better alternative that doesn't seem to work yet. There must be more encouraging methods of improving on each others input.

Comment: Oh, haha.  I thought that's what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it is too late,but i did it anyways for everyone searching the solution for it,i assume you want to change it every time u press capslock to be different text:

```
    CapsLock::
CapsLock0:
    {
    SendRaw Hi 
    Sleep 500
    KeyWait, CapsLock, D
    {
    Goto CapsLock1
    }
    }
    Return

CapsLock1:
    {
    SendRaw How Are you 
    Sleep 500
    KeyWait, CapsLock, D
    {
    Goto CapsLock2
    }
    }
    Return

CapsLock2:
    {
    SendRaw I am Fine
    Sleep 500
    KeyWait, CapsLock, D
    {
    Goto CapsLock0
    }
    }
    Return
```

Explaination for Sleep,it is used because if you would press CapsLock without it then 2 of the command blocks would be executed,it is especially needed.

Answer (score -1):

How about this...

```
Capslock::
Send, Hi{Enter}
Sleep, 400 ; sleep briefly to allow the CapsLock key to be released
KeyWait, Capslock, D
Send, How Are you?{Enter}
Sleep, 400
KeyWait, Capslock, D
Send, I am fine Thank you.{Enter}
Return
```

How about this...

```
Capslock::
Send, Hi{Enter}
KeyWait, Capslock, U
KeyWait, Capslock, D
Send, How Are you?{Enter}
KeyWait, Capslock, U
KeyWait, Capslock, D
Send, I am fine Thank you.{Enter}
Return
```

Comment: Sleep isn't a reliable way to determine if a key has been released.  What if the user holds it for a half second?